# AJax will not display a text file onto the screen?

Tags: ajax

I am new to AJAX and am experimenting with a simple page that should show a txt file into a specific location. At this point it does not show the vlist.txt file.

Question: Why does this code not display the file (vlist.txt)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\vlist.txt");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2>This is where your text will go</div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

New Code that was Tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load(function() {alert( "Load was performed." ););
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2>This is where your text will go</div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

No alert box was displayed so I am not sure that it is even getting to that point.

Comment: Check if load was successfull: $("#div1").load( "...", function() {   alert( "Load was performed." );
});

Comment: I put that in the function and no alert box was shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$().load()` can't be used with a local file path like `C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\vlist.txt`.

Put your file on a web server and your code will most likely work.

Comment: What can a person do for testing purposes. I do not have local access to a server, so is there a way that you can test in the pc world on a regular desktop?

Comment: @DougHauf you can install a web server on your computer, for example on Windows I use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) which includes Apache, PHP and MySQL.